# Issue with backups failing on Bacula

Tags: bacula

I'm new to Bacula, and I've inherited an environment that was already setup and deployed. Recently one of our servers that we have always backed up crashed and was deemed no longer of any use, so I was tasked to remove it from the client list, which I did. Since I've removed it, every morning I have jobs failing and I can see from the email I receive that it's looking to copy an old job:

```
15-Jun 01:00 bacula-dir JobId 56332: Copying using JobId=55657 Job=server2-fd.2022-05-31_18.00.01_46
15-Jun 01:00 bacula-dir JobId 56332: Fatal error: Previous Job resource not found for "server2-fd".
15-Jun 01:00 bacula-dir JobId 56332: Error: Bacula bacula-dir 9.4.2 (04Feb19):
  Build OS:               x86_64-pc-linux-gnu redhat Enterprise release
  Prev Backup JobId:      55657
  Prev Backup Job:        server2-fd.2022-05-31_18.00.01_46
  New Backup JobId:       0
  Current JobId:          56332
  Current Job:            CopyDiskToTape.2022-06-15_01.00.01_17
  Backup Level:           Incremental
```

I can't find any indication of server2 in any of my jobs and I'm not sure how to get rid of these errors. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a utility called dbcheck. Comes with bacula, allowed me to check for orphaned client records.